# passportjs authentication failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate users using passportjs for the first time but I've been having trouble getting it to work. So this is the relevant code I'm working with

Index.js route file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: 'home',
    failureRedirect: '/'
}));
```

app.js

```
// Authentication packages
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);

    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);

        if (err) {return done(err)};

        if (user.length === 0) {
            done(null, false);
        };

        const hash = user[0].password.toString();
        console.log(hash);

        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
            if (res === true) {
                return done(null, {user_id: user[0].id});
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
}
));
```

When i input a valid email address and password, I don't get redirected to the home like i want. Instead I'm redirected back to the login page. Same thing happens when i use an invalid email address. I also don't see the email and password even though I'm trying to console log it when i submit the login form.

Can anyone help me out here please.

Comment: if you don't see the console.log you're trying to do, it means that the entire function you are trying to hit, isn't hit. Which means it will fail every time, showing you the login screen again. Figure out why it's not hitting your code, and you will find the answer you are looking for

Comment: Here is an example you can go through to check where you may be making a mistake: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately I have been at this for 2 days running now and haven't been able to figure it out. Should i move the strategy from app.js into index.js instead?

Comment: @zerohero followed the example and I couldn't find one thing I'm doing differently from What i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you have `email` as the username. I had a similar problem and found that the solution was just to add `usernameField` to the strategy options:

`new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, done){...})`

Comment: Added the `new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, res, done){return done(null, 'user')})` and that works fine. But adding my database query `res.locals.connection.query('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function(err, user) {...}` is throwing this error `Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may either need to place your `passport.use` in your route index.js file, or somehow pass the `passport` instance  created in app.js as a parameter to index.js

Could you try that? It's possible that a new instance is created everytime you do require('passport')